# How many 'pubs' (alehouses, inns and taverns) were there in England in 1577?

Tags: england, demography, tudor-period

I came across an interesting bit of demographic information while listening to [a lecture](https://www.gresham.ac.uk/lectures-and-events/how-the-middle-ages-were-built-coming-of-age-1408-1530):

> From early times people had rented out space in their houses for
> travellers, but by the thirteenth century Inns became common in most
> towns of any size. Inns were like hotels. Taverns, which provided good
> quality food and drink, including wine, were more like restaurants.
> Alehouses were pubs providing basic food, ale and on occasion rooms.
> From the sixteenth century these distinctions were recognised in law
> and defined licensing restrictions and the obligations of landlords.
> From a **census** taken in **1577** we can calculate that there were then
> around ***17,367 alehouses, 1,991 Inns and 401 taverns*** in England

Looks like the answer, right? Unfortunately, since this is a video lecture, ***it provided *no source* for the information.***

Looking to the internet was not helpful to say the least (emphasis mine):

- > A **1577 census** of England recorded the existence of ***14,202
  > alehouses***,  [*source*](https://brumafriend.medium.com/the-dangers-of-the-early-modern-alehouse-7eee4a8a306e#:%7E:text=Alehouses%20were%20common%20in%20early,the%20common%20person%20to%20relax.)
- > By **1577** it is estimated that there were some ***17,000 alehouses***, 2,000
  > inns and 400 taverns throughout England and
  > Wales.  [*source*](https://www.historic-uk.com/CultureUK/The-Great-British-Pub/)
- > England had many ***alehouses***. Clark estimates from a **survey conducted in
  > 1577** that the number was ***24,000***, or one for every 142 inhabitants
  > [*source*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057%2F9781403913937_4)

Seems like quite a *range of answers* showing up.

All these sources seem to agree that *somewhere*, from 1577, there is ***a primary source*** of information, but nobody is gathering the same facts from this source. We know this source is either a census or survey. Research showed that the [Ale Houses Act 1551](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ale_Houses_Act_1551) may have been responsible for the collection of this data.

Secondary sources appear to be inconsistent. So it appears to answer to this question will require the location and accurate interpretation of this ***primary source*** from 1577. (If you find a secondary source you feel is correct, please explain why it should be considered *definitively* correct.)

The wide variety of answers floating around the web seems to indicate a correct accounting needs to be done.

So, how many [pubs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pub) ( *'alehouses', 'taverns' and 'inns'*) *were* there in England in 1577.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something that might serve as a reference...

> Survey of inns, taverns and alehouses in England and Wales in 1577:
> National Archives SP 12/115-19. London, Bristol and Norwich are
> excluded and some other returns are patchy. R. Flenley (ed.), A
> Calendar of the Register of the Queen's Majesty's Council in the
> Dominion and the Principality of Wales ... 1569-91, Cymmrodorion
> Society Record Series 8 (1916) gives the figures for 7 Welsh counties
> and for Worcestershire.

Found at [this](https://www.buildinghistory.org/buildings/inns.shtml) site. [Here's](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/) a link to the National Archives.

Comment: Thanks! Some good info in the source list at that site.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of the archived material hasn't been digitized...

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunate, I was really hoping to get a look at that document...

Comment: [Here's some quasi-contact info for Simon Thurley](https://www.bl.uk/people/experts/simon-thurley). You might try dropping an email and explain who you are, what you're doing, and what you need. Academics are often more than willing to answer reasonable questions. There is also [this one](https://research.sas.ac.uk/search/fellow/1203/dr-simon-thurley/) which has a direct email address.